# pandas groupy.min() auto convert float64 to object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

tried to select from a dataframe by value, actually by the minimum value and doing the following:

```
results[results['d1']==min_overall['d1']['cao3']]
```

the above gave me error msg like comparsion by diff types.

then i checked the following:

```
results['d1'].dtypes : float64
min_overall['d1'].dtypes : object
```

what make feel strange is: ('cao3' is one of the type)

```
days=[1,2,5,10,20,50,100]
stock_analysis=pd.DataFrame(columns=['d'+str(d) for d in days],dtype=np.float64)
results=pd.concat([stockpicks,stock_analysis],axis=1)
results_typed=results.groupby('type')
min_overall=results_typed.min()
```

that is min_overall is calculated from results with groupby. but the 'd1' column is converted from float64 to object.

why? and how could i overcome that?

EDIT: here below the format of results

```
         date  type stocknum  price      pe        d1        d2        d5  \
0  2014-02-17  cao3  0326.HK   0.20   20.00        95        95        95   
1  2014-02-17  cao3  0536.HK   2.56   25.60  99.21875       100  97.65625   
2  2014-02-17  cao3  0595.HK   0.97   48.50       100  107.2165  104.1237   
3  2014-02-17  cao3  0698.HK   0.95   15.83  102.1053  97.89474  97.89474   
4  2014-02-17  cao3  0759.HK   3.25  108.33  95.38462  94.15385        92   

        d10  
0        90  
1   89.0625  
2  93.81443  
3  105.2632  
4  90.15385  

[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

here below added more codes and outputs:

```
df=pd.read_csv(logfile,header=None,names=['date','type','stocknum','price','pe'])
stockpicks=df.drop_duplicates()
days=[1,2,5,10,20,50,100]
stock_analysis=pd.DataFrame(columns=['d'+str(d) for d in days],dtype=np.float64)

results=pd.concat([stockpicks,stock_analysis],axis=1)
results_typed=results.groupby('type')
max_overall=results_typed.max()
min_overall=results_typed.min()

print(results['d2'])
print(results.dtypes)
print(min_overall['d2'])
print(min_overall.dtypes)

print(results[results['d1']==min_overall['d1']['cao3']])
```

and the outputs: you can see all the d columns are of float64, but become objects after groupby min.

```
0      95.000000
1      99.218750
2     100.000000
3     102.105263
4      95.384615
5      98.400000
6      96.250000
7     100.000000
8     100.000000
9      96.969697
10    101.675978
11     98.953975
12     94.594595
13     96.969697
14    101.882845
...
4078    101.590106
4079     98.083067
4080    100.341297
4081     97.805643
4082    103.225806
4083     99.137931
4084    102.302632
4085    102.941176
4086     98.083067
4087    104.246285
4088    102.967359
4089    101.224490
4090     99.502488
4091     99.789474
4092    104.380952
Name: d1, Length: 3739, dtype: float64
date         object
type         object
stocknum     object
price       float64
pe          float64
d1          float64
d2          float64
d5          float64
d10         float64
d20         float64
d50         float64
d100        float64
dtype: object
type
bbom    4.01267828
bbos    4.01267828
cao3    4.01267828
maos    4.01267828
rscp    78.6096256
Name: d2, dtype: object
date        object
stocknum    object
price       object
pe          object
d1          object
d2          object
d5          object
d10         object
d20         object
d50         object
d100        object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you post code and data to reproduce your problem, thanks

Comment: Can you explain more what this line is trying to achieve: `results[results['d1']==min_overall['d1']['cao3']]`? are you looking for where `d1` matches the other `d1` values and then display `type` column?

Comment: min_overall is the group mean by 'type', min_overall['d1']['cao3'] should get the min value of type 'cao3' at column 'd1'. this compares to the column 'd1' of the original dataframe results, suppose to select a row of results.

Comment: what failed me is the fact that min_overall['d1'] is actually of object type. so raise error when compare to the 'd1' of the original results. what i wonder is why the type of the same column 'd1' would become object (str??) after groupby and min.

Comment: But then aren't you comparing `d1` which is a float to a type which is a `string`? I'm confused. Can you post short snippets of data so that we can reproduce your data structures, it must be runnable otherwise this becomes frustrating

Comment: @EdChum, i didn't mean to compare a float to a str. the group mean is calcualted from the dataframe results, at least where the column 'd1' is float64. i dunno why group mean turn out to become object.

Comment: @EdChum, added codes and outputs. the key point here is the conversion from float64 to object after groupby min...

Comment: I think you may be confused or I don't understand, if I do `df.groupby('type')['d1'].dtype` then I see that the dtype is `object` but I think that refers to the `groupby` object not the column dtype, if I do `df.groupby('type')['d1'].head()` then it shows that the type is still `float64`, if you do `type(df.groupby('type')['d1'])` then the output is `pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy`

Comment: @EdChum, you get me wrong. pls note the lines, min_overall=results_typed.min() and print(min_overall.dtypes), and the output. i am talking about the group min, you may compare those columns of the original result and the group min, the dtypes of the columns changed from float to obj.